# (android) How to detect if phone is muted while ringing

Tags: android, ringtone, mute

I am trying to develop an android application which requires detection of if phone is muted during an incoming call is active(ringing). Some phones have a mute button which instantly mute the sound of the call but does not stop the call (phone is ringing in silent).

Before the call, phone is not muted, but when the call begins, user decides to mute the phone with this button. I want to determine if this situation is happened or not.

I tried to read RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION but it seems that this button does not change the RINGER_MODE(Maybe I am wrong).

So how can I do that?